# Why does the speed in Pentaho insert/update step became 0 r/s?

Tags: pentaho

I'm working a Data migration job and when it comes to the insert/update, the speed is really slow. And it even reached 0 after 20min.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases what I do is separate the flow and execute three transformations: One transformation separates the rows to insert and the rows to update (into two separate files/temporary tables or mark them with insert/update flag and store them in the same file/temp table). A second transformation perform the inserts and a third transformation performs the updates.

I found the Insert/update very slow, so as soon as the target reaches some (unknown to me) size, separating the inserts from the updates and performing them separately is much quicker.